# Does Esther 4:16 contradict Esther 5:1-5?

Tags: contradiction, chronology, esther

In Esther 4:16, when Esther is about to risk her life to save the Jews, she first tells the Jews in Shushan to fast for three days, **night and day**, and that she would do the same. However, in 5:1-5, we're now told it's “the third day” of the fast (5:1, NKJV), but Esther invites the king and Haman to come "today" for a meal she's prepared (5:4, NKJV).

Since Esther said she would "neither eat nor drink for three days, **night or day**" (4:16, NKJV, emphasis mine), why does she apparently do so on the third day of the fast? Would the Jews have understood the terminology of 4:16 to have *ended* on "the third day" (5:1, NKJV), perhaps?

Comment: Is there any indication that Esther broke *her* fast? One can serve a feast without partaking of it oneself.

Comment: @RayButterworth I was thinking of that as another way to reconcile the verses. In this case, though, would you agree with Dottard's explanation that, per inclusive time reckoning, as he calls it, "three days and nights" would have been considered ended on the third day?

Comment: I usually agree with Dottard, but not necessarily in this case. (E.g. we definitely disagree on the Crucifixion timetable.)

Comment: @RayButterworth Doesn't Ignatius (or someone who added the quote in the 5th century), without flinching, say the Friday-Sunday timetable fits the sign of Jonah? If so, might this suggest that our view of what a day and night must mean is different from what it used to be?

Comment: @RayButterworth Here's the quote I'm referencing: "On the day of the preparation, […] He was crucified […] and before sunset He was buried. During the Sabbath He continued under the earth in the tomb […]. At the dawning of the Lord's day He arose from the dead, according to what was spoken by Himself, ‘As Jonah was three days and three nights in the whale's belly, so shall the Son of man also be three days and three nights in the heart of the earth.’" (Epistle of Ignatius to the Trallians, Chap IX, https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Ante-Nicene_Christian_Library/Epistle_to_the_Trallians)

Comment: “*At the dawning of the Lord's day He arose*” is enough to dismiss the authority of this human interpretation.  The women went while it was still dark to find him already risen.

Answer (score 2):

This in Esther 4:16-5:5 is an excellent example of what is generally understood to be "Inclusive Time Reckoning".  That is, when people counted time, they included incomplete parts of the first and last period as whole units.  See appendix below for more examples.

Jesus' time in the grave was said to be three days, but it was only part of Friday, all of Saturday, and part of Sunday.  See Luke 24:21.

In the case of Esther, let us suppose that her discussion and decision with Mordecai  occurred on (say) Monday afternoon.  Esther says that she and her maids will fast for three days.  So, on Wednesday afternoon (only 48 hours later), on the "third day" she will have completed, according their customary reckoning, three days of fasting.

**APPENDIX - Inclusive Time Reckoning**

When the ancient Hebrew counted time they used what we now call “Inclusive Time Reckoning”.  This means counting the first and last incomplete time periods (days or months or years) as whole units.  Here are some examples of this type of time keeping:

- Luke 13:32, “Behold, I cast out demons and perform cures today and tomorrow, and the third day I reach My goal.”
- in 2 Kings 18:9-10. The siege of Samaria lasted from the fourth to the sixth year of Hezekiah, which is equated with the seventh to the ninth year of Hoshea, and yet the city is said to have been taken “at the end of three years.”
- Jeroboam II of Israel succeeded his father Jehoash in the 15th year of Amaziah of Judah (2 Kings 14:23), and Amaziah “lived after the death of Jehoash … of Israel fifteen years” (2 Kings 14:17). A modern reader would mentally add 15 to 15, reaching Amaziah’s 30th year, yet Amaziah reigned only 29 years (verse 2).
- Acts 10:30 records a clear period of 72 hours that is reckoned as “four days ago,” not “three”.

Comment: "*Monday afternoon … Wednesday afternoon (only 48 hours later)*".  Would this third-day counting still be true if it were instead Wednesday morning (42 hours)? And if the fast had begun late on Monday (say 38 hours)? Or if were even earlier on Wednesday, shortly after sunset (26 hours)?

Comment: What bothers me is that this reasoning implies that the phrase “*neither eat nor drink for three days, night or day*” could apply to the Yom Kippur fast, which is normally considered as *one day* even though it lasts 25 hours (an extra half hour at each sunset just to be sure). Would anyone ever speak of “fasting for three days, night and day”, as what happens on the Day of Atonement?

Comment: @RayButterworth - in fact that is just what happened with Jesus' burial.  If died and was buried (say) I hour before sunset on Friday and was resurrected (say) one or two hours before sunrise on Sunday morning, He was in the grace about 35 or 36 hours; but counted as three days.  We see this numerous times in the chronology of the kings.

Comment: @RayButterworth Another example is Leviticus 7:15-17 where the third day is the day after tomorrow.  So this is the idiom at least as far back as the time of Moses.  "The third day" is equivalent to "after three days" since the two phrases are used interchangeably in the gospels, and after "three days and three nights" is the same, used once. "3 days, night and day" is also the same.  Night and day is, I think, simply referring to a 24 hour day as opposed to a "day" which could mean just that portion of 24 hours which is in daylight.